# FileField: force using TemporaryUploadedFile

Tags: django, django-file-upload

When uploading a file for a field such as this one:

```
file = FileField(upload_to='/path/')
```

Django uses either an `InMemoryUploadedFile` or a `TemporaryUploadedFile`. The latter is stored on the disk and its file name can be accessed with the `temporary_file_path` property. The storage choice depends on the file size.

**How can I override this behaviour and always upload as a `TemporaryUploadedFile` for this model field?**

The reason I am asking this is because I need to write a validator that uses an external library that can only take file paths as input, no data streams.

Answer (score 11):

By default the [upload handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS) are:

```
[
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
```

And files smaller than 2.5MB are handled with `MemoryFileUploadHandler`.

So just say in your settings:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',]
```

Comment: I need to tune this on specific fields only. Can that be applied to my ``file`` field only?